# How to keep clickable text from highlighting Android?

Tags: android, string, colors

I have set specific words in a string clickable, and although the functionality is working, the text always highlights a blue color until you press outside of the clickable text onto non-clickable text. Also note that inflating views or pressing any other buttons will keep the text highlighted too. It seems that you have to click on the non-clickable text area to get rid of the highlighted clickable text. How can I prevent the text from highlighting after I click on my clickable selected words? Here is my setup

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.my_string)));

        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Logger.i(TAG, "clicked on clickable words");
            }
        };

        // makes the words clickable
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 10, 23, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        // makes the clickable words remain red link instead of blue
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red)), 30, 43, 0);
        tv.setText(ss);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Anyone have any ideas for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, `tv.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` works. And is the easiest solution compared to overriding ClickableSpan and trying to do something like

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.View;

public class WordSpan extends ClickableSpan 
{

    private int id;
    private TextPaint textpaint;
    public boolean shouldHilightWord = false;
    public WordSpan(int anID, String txt, int selected) {
        id =anID;
        // if the word selected is the same as the ID set the highlight flag
        if(selected == id)  {
            shouldHilightWord = true;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        textpaint = ds;
        ds.setColor(ds.linkColor);
        if(shouldHilightWord){
            textpaint.bgColor = Color.GRAY;         
            textpaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

        }
        //Remove default underline associated with spans
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);

    }

    public void changeSpanBgColor(View widget){
        shouldHilightWord = true;
        updateDrawState(textpaint);
        widget.invalidate();


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    /**
     * This function sets the span to record the word number, as the span ID
     * @param spanID
     */
    public void setSpanTextID(int spanID){
        id = spanID;
    }

    /**
     * Return the wordId of this span
     * @return id
     */
    public int getSpanTextID(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this answer will save someone a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to remove all color spans from Spannable string :

```
ForegroundColorSpan[] colorSpans =  ss.getSpans(0, ss.length(), ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    for(ForegroundColorSpan colorSpan : colorSpans){
        ss.removeSpan(colorSpan);
    }
```

Comment: No, this does not work. I want the foreground color to remain red, however, I do not want after the clickable text is selected to highlight.